# What is the meaning of "rolling"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I hear "Roll" as a verb in different sentences. The meanings that I find in dictionaries do not fully explain the exact meaning in those sentences.

For instance, in the following sentence :
  "We will be rolling the new feature by the end of week."

What is the exact meaning of "rolling"?

PS: Seems like "roll" in this sentence is actually "roll out". The new question is : Is it so common to omit "out" and just say "roll" instead of "roll out"?

Comment: English _phrasal verbs_ like "_roll **out**_" consist of a verb and a preposition, and the preposition is very important. Many dictionaries provide a definition of the idiomatic  phrasal verb **_[to roll out](http://www.onelook.com/?w=roll+out&ls=a)_**. Be sure to read text carefully, always consult more than one dictionary, and be sure to consult _English language_ dictionaries, not "translation dictionaries" in your native language or services like Google "translate." They will not help you. The _[OneLook dictionary](http://OneLook.com)_ is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have actually read the meaning of "roll out" but I was not sure if by "roll" they actually mean "roll out".@P.E.Dant

Comment: You are quite welcome, @Maryam. Be sure to make a bookmark for the **_[OneLook dictionary](http://onelook.com)_**. This is a valuable resource, especially for learners of English. Thank you for your question—and we hope you will ask more of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the sentence was "We will be rolling *out* the new feature by the end of the week". In this context, to **roll out** means to introduce to the public. It implies a smooth motion (figuratively) from the environment where the team is making the feature to the users. Just *rolling* instead of *rolling out* is not normal English usage in this context, though the intended meaning is clear.

To answer the edit, no, just saying *roll* instead of *roll out* is unnatural and I've never seen anyone do it. *Roll out* what we'd call a *phrasal verb*, which means the preposition is a part of the verb itself, and neither can be understood without the other. Don't drop the *out*!